# Getting excel export data with fixed header in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I am using DocumentFormat.OpenXml to exporting my data into excel form.

Following code I am using to form excel data:
 (Where I can modify so that,I can freeze the header?)

```
public static MemoryStream GetStreamFromDataSet(List<WorkSheetData> worksheetDataObjects)
{
    MemoryStream stream = SpreadsheetReader.Create();
    using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadSheet =
        SpreadsheetDocument.Open(stream, true))
    {                
        for (int i = 0; i < worksheetDataObjects.Count; i++)
        {
            WorksheetPart newWorkSheetPart =
                spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
            newWorkSheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(new SheetData());
            newWorkSheetPart.Worksheet.Save();
            Sheets sheets =
                spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>();
            string relationshipId =
                spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(newWorkSheetPart);
            uint sheetId = (uint)i;
            if (sheets.Elements<Sheet>().Count() > 0)
            {
                sheetId = sheets.Elements<Sheet>().Select(s =>
                    s.SheetId.Value).Max() + 1;
            }

            Sheet sheet = new Sheet()
            {
                Id = relationshipId,
                SheetId = sheetId,
                Name = worksheetDataObjects[i].TabName
            };

            sheets.Append(sheet);
            WorksheetWriter writer =
                new WorksheetWriter(spreadSheet, newWorkSheetPart);
            SpreadsheetStyle style =
                SpreadsheetReader.GetDefaultStyle(spreadSheet);
            style.SetBorder("000000", BorderStyleValues.Thin);
            style.IsBold = true;                    
            for (int x = 0; x < worksheetDataObjects[i].dataTable.Columns.Count; x++)
            {
                string columnName = GetExcelColumnValue(x + 1);
                writer.PasteText(columnName + "1",
                    worksheetDataObjects[i].dataTable.Columns[x].ColumnName, style);
            }

            style.IsBold = false;
            writer.PasteDataTable(worksheetDataObjects[i].dataTable, "A2", style);
            spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Save();
        }

        //Remove first 3 default tabs (Sheet1 ~ Sheet3) 
        spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets.FirstChild.Remove();
        spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets.FirstChild.Remove();
        spreadSheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets.FirstChild.Remove();
    };

    return stream;            
}
```

The above code I am using to have my all data to be downloaded in excel.

Please help me out..!

Answer (score 0):

This post might help:

[Export To Excel](http://www.up2technology.com/blog/export-to-excel-using-c/)

Check for

```
ws1.View.FreezePanes(2, 1);
```

Comment: No Mandar I am using Openxml dll for doing operations.Thanks for your reply.Please suggest me if you have any solution for doing fixed header using Openxml .I used this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/e1c08add-b610-44c9-b60e-fa8ef6c24978/openxmlexcelc?forum=oxmlsdk but it not helps me.